# Divide two strings in Java

Tags: java

In Java, how can I divide two different strings, and return the quotient of the two strings as a String?

Here's the function that I'm trying to implement:

```
public static String divideTwoStrings(string1, string2){
    //this function should convert both strings to doubles,
    //and then return their quotient as a string
}
```

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(String)` can parse, the math should be easy, too.

Comment: Double.parseDouble(String)?

Comment: I don't understand the reason for all the downvotes. I know that this question isn't difficult to answer, but how does that make it a bad question?

Comment: @AndersonGreen it is phrased a bit ridiculously and presumably the OP knows how to divide two numbers so what they really want to know is how to "Convert a string to a double"

Comment: @AndersonGreen p.s didn't realise you are the OP

Comment: @AndersonGreen: The question isn't bad.  But it could have been asked, "How do you convert from a String to a Double and vice versa?"  And to get your answer, you could have googled.  I didn't downvote, btw.

Comment: I'm not sure division is an operator defined for the `String` type.  What does divide two strings mean?  Are we taking substrings from the first string based on contents of the second string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, you'll need [Double.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29).  This will turn the two strings into a Double.  Then you can divide them like normal.  Take the result of that, and call [String.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28double%29) on that to turn it back into a String.

This will return "0.7857142857142857"

```
public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(divideTwoStrings("5.5", "7"));
    }

    public static String divideTwoStrings(String string1, String string2) {
        return String.valueOf(Double.valueOf(string1) / Double.valueOf(string2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Double.valueOf needlessly creates a Double, if you use Double.parseDouble it returns a `double`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's not something *I* care about in general.  I'm comfortable assuming the compiler will optimize that for me.  And even if it doesn't, I've rarely written code where this would be the bottleneck.

Comment: I suspect this is true for the OP also.  I work on ultra low GC systems were creating objects needlessly is the first thing you optimise away (and the EscapeAnalysis is still not smart enough yet)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Fortunately, the readability does not suffer for that preoptimization.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a good reason to use `String`s instead of `double`s a better choice might eb to use BigDecimal to do the calculation. e.g.

```
public static void main(String... ignore) {
    System.out.println(divideTwoStrings("123456789.0123456790", "11223344.5566778899"));
}

public static String divideTwoStrings(String string1, String string2) {
    BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(string1);
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(string2);
    return a.divide(b, a.scale(), RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toString();
}
```

prints

```
10.9999999010
```

Comment: +1 for using `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I usually prefer to use double over BigDecimal but in this case, I believe it's the most sensible choice.

Comment: Indeed. It's more suitable here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String divideTwoStrings(String string1, String string2){
     double d1 = Double.parseDouble(string1), d2 = Double.parseDouble(string2);
     double division = d1 / d2;
     return division + "";
}
```